# Not able to send the direct message

Tags: twitter

I got an error while sending direct message using MGTwitterEngine in my app

Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"

I have searched a lot but not getting any proper solution. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error would appear to indicate that you have a permissions problem.  The body of the response often contains helpful information that identifies the issue.

Are other parts of your application working correctly?  If not, then your problem may be related to OAuth.

Comment: but other part is working correctly but only the DM is not working...I have tried a lot of ways but not succeed....

Comment: You can't send a direct message unless both the sender and recipient are following each other.  Have you confirmed this is true?

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you're using a library that doesn't appear to have been updated in two and a half years.  I checked the MGTwitterEngine GitHub and the last commit was in September of 2010.  The Twitter API has changed quite a bit since then and MGTwitterEngine may no longer be in sync with the API.